# Allow Multiple Downloads in ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to download multiple files in Chrome using ChromeDriver ( C# ), first file is downloaded successfully, but the anothers not download, appeared a window asking "Download Multiple Files - Allow | Block "

I need to configure to download automatic. In Preferences of Chrome have this options "Settings -> Content Settings -> Automatic Downloads -> Allow all sites do download multiple files automatically"

I need to configure in "ChromeOptions" like in example

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("...", true);
```

Below is the image with Chrome message

[image: Window of Chrome message]

Answer (score 23):

I found the solution. Just add a preference:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for posting the solution. This was the only thing that worked for me!

Comment: This stopped working after version 87.0.4280.88.
Does anyone have an alternative?

Comment: found the way? i am also looking solution for this